# Proof linearity of direct sum in Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I'm reading the text [fundamentals of linear algebra and optimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.739.5762&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [the last paragraph in p.77], it's said the direct sum is a linear map, but I cannot see why :

Given $X$, $Y$ subspace of a vector space $E$, we define a map 
$$ f \left\{
\begin{array}
\\ X \times Y \rightarrow E \\ (x,y) \rightarrow x+y\end{array}\right.$$
Then for any $\lambda \neq 0$ 
$$ f(x_1+\lambda x_2,y) = x_1+\lambda x_2+y$$
And 
$$ f(x_1,y)+\lambda f(x_2,y) = x_1+\lambda x_2+ (1+\lambda)y$$
So it cannot be linear on the first position (coordinate) since $f(x_1+\lambda x_2,y) \neq f(x_1,y)+\lambda f(x_2,y)$. Where am I wrong? How the text say $f$ is clearly linear?

Comment: You're not using the product vector space structure on $X\times Y$. For $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ and $\lambda\in k$, $\lambda(x,y)=(\lambda x,\lambda y)$ and for $(x',y')\in X\times Y$, $(x,y)+(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')$.

Comment: Check your last line, where did $f$ go?